# How to make a wedge shape in fabricjs

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to create a wedge/sector shape that starts at an angle of 0° and animates over a second to a full angle of 360° (So to animate the below shape to a full circle).

[image]

I can't find a shape in the library to do this so I'm guessing that I'm going to have to make the shape myself. What's the best way to approach this?

I have a wedge shape (pictured above) that I made in illustrator and have the relevant path details:

```
<path d="M1951,1818c0-429.2-4-1065.3-4-1500c89,0,176.3,7.8,261,22.6C2131,783,1951,1818,1951,1818z"/>
```

..so would I have to modify the cubic bezier value in this path manually?

I'm new to canvas so I don't know what's the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Animating a Sector / Circle

Use a clippath to show only part of the circle and progressively make the clippath smaller showing the rest of it.

```
var endAngle = 0;
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    ...
    clipTo: function (ctx) {
        // the center is relative to the object - hence 0, 0 instead of 100, 100
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        // the endAngle is the global variable we animate from 0 to 360 degrees (2 * PI)
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, endAngle);
    }
});

// changing the clippath
(function animate() {
    fabric.util.animate({
        startValue: 0,
        endValue: 2 * Math.PI,
        duration: 1000,
        onChange: function (value) {
            endAngle = value;
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    });
})();
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nyjzs32p/